# How to drastically reduce firebase calls when a post is updated for a media application

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, server, social-networking

I am currently developing a social media application and ran into a scalability issue. The issue is best explained using an example. Lets say a person has 200k followers and creates a post. Now, when the person updates their post by changing the description perhaps, this will then make 200k calls to firebase to update the posts in each user's feeds. Another way is to load all the posts for the user upon opening the app, but this will require a system to load these posts that does not make a call for every new post they want to see. I am looking for a solution to this calls problem, as 200k calls in firebase would be incredibly expensive. Thank you for any and all help that you provide, and I appreciate all your time!

Answer (score 1):

You could consider Firestore bundles, which allow you to read content through the through server API/SDKs once and then distribute that bundle of content to your clients out-of-band, where you then use a client-side API to insert the content into the local cache.

For more on this, see:

- The [Load Data Faster and Lower Your Costs with Firestore Data Bundles!](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2021/04/firestore-supports-data-bundles.html) blog post
- The documentation on [Firestore bundles](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/bundles)
- The [Serve bundled Firestore content from a CDN](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/serve-bundles) solution guide

Comment: Awesome thank you! I will look into it